# Java - How to split a string "abcdefghijklmnopq" into an array of strings [abc,def,ghi,jkl,lmn,opq]

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am writing a program that needs to convert every three characters into a corresponding value, this means I need to store every three characters of the string into an array, I am unsure how to approach this, any ideas?

A friend showed me a brute force method;

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = kb.next();
int n = input.length()/3;
String[] num = new String[n];

for(int i = 0, x=0, y=3; i<n; i++){
num[i]  = input.substring(x,y);
x += 3;
y += 3;
System.out.println(num[i]);
}
```

Comment: What have you thought of so far? Can you solve an easier problem first, like splitting the string into two strings?

Comment: Can you show your code that you have so far?

Comment: I thought of using substrings and a loop to assign every three values into the array but it didn't really work to well

Comment: Thankyou for the find dasblinkenlight

Comment: this should be an interview question :P

Comment: String input="abcdefghijkl";
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("[a-z]{1,3}").matcher(input);
while(m.find())
System.out.println(m.group(0));